# How can I run facebook-chat-api from Github with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, facebook, api

Can anyone please tell me step-by-step how to run facebook-chat-api from Github (https://github.com/Schmavery/facebook-chat-api)? I use Ubuntu 14.04 and already tried it with npm but it didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Facebook has no Chat API.

Comment: The Messenger API is for communication between one user and a page. Any system that tries to build a user-to-user chat based on it would be misusing that API.

Answer (score 1):

As people have commented, this isn't an official api, and might not be what you should be using, depending on your situation.  It isn't stable by design, and requires the use of your username and password.  These are frequently undesirable things when making software, but occasionally there's no better option.  You may or may not have more luck with the official messenger api: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform

I would normally suggest submitting on issue on the GitHub repo, so that the owners of it (me) can more easily figure out exactly what's going wrong and help you more.

To answer your question, the steps should be as follows. This will install `facebook-chat-api` from the GitHub repo master branch instead of npm. (I'm assuming that's what you want).

1. Install npm
2. `npm init` to create a new npm project.
3. Open the generated package.json and add this line to your dependencies. You can see https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#github-urls for more information about this.

   `"facebook-chat-api": "git://github.com/schmavery/facebook-chat-api"`
4. Run `npm i` to install dependencies.
5. Create the following file, call it test.js

```
    var login = require("facebook-chat-api");

    // Create simple echo bot
    login({email: "FB_EMAIL", password: "FB_PASSWORD"}, function callback (err, api) {
        if(err) return console.error(err);

        api.listen(function callback(err, message) {
            api.sendMessage(message.body, message.threadID);
        });
    });
```

5. Replace "FB_EMAIL" and "FB_PASSWORD" with your login information for the account that you want to use.  Note that this is just an example, if you make anything more serious or want to use version control, you need to manage these values more securely.
6. Run `node test.js`.
7. This might result in an error.  If so, open an issue and wait for feedback :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did all the steps you provide. When performing `node test.js` the terminal does nothing and it's giving me a new line to enter new commands. Is it possible that I'm using the wrong version? I installed `npm` and `node` from ubuntu repository.